# Css: box shadow only for 3 or less borders?

Tags: css

i have a box with a border going all around it as well as a box shadow and an outline. However, i dont need the box shadow for the top border so i want to make it disappear but WITHOUT MOVING THE BOX DOWN. Is it possible to do that? If not, what other alternative i have?

This is my code:

```
.box {
  background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover  transparent;
  border: 4px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #826200;
  outline: 2px solid white;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x7rrj/

Comment: Can u Fiddle your code?

Comment: Fiddle is been added.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/sA6Fh/)

You can't remove only top box shadow. But you can hide it. As per your code

```
.box {
 background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover  transparent;
 border: 4px solid black;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 0 5px red;
 outline: 2px solid white;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}
```

You can use the above css.

**EDIT**
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/x7rrj/1/)

Yeah it is messy at the bottom . So see my alternative solution. Enlcose the div with a container and add border property. It ll not be messy

**EDIT** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/sA6Fh/1/)

CSS only solution using before pseudo element and border property.

Comment: Must i have to specify the width and height? Because the size of my box is variable.

Comment: No need :) You need to modify css according to it.

Comment: Ah, i had already tried that but it only moves the shadow box 1 pixel down so now the bottom will look messy.

Comment: @Cain post a fiddle to look into it

Comment: Please look back at my question.

Comment: @CainNuke deleted my answer since this one already solves your issue. Voted up. You should accept this answer

Comment: I didnt delete anything. What you mean?

Comment: @CainNuke I voluntarily deleted my answer because it was redundant...that's what I mean

Comment: Ahh, i see. Anyway, this answer resolves the problem but not my question because it requires to modify my html and i intended to do it with css only if possible. Sorry about the confusion, my mistake.

Comment: Looks great, but must i specify width and height? Because as i had already said, my box size is variable.

Comment: Yes You must :) If varies, use javascript or jquery to set width

Answer (score 0):

You can't specifically just remove the top box shadow. However, you can adjust the y-axis so it doesn't appear at the top, but it moves the whole box-shadow down.

For example, try

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 0 5px #826200;
```

This moves the shadow down 4 pixels. -4px would move it up 4 pixels which is the opposite of what you want.

So see how 4px looks to you, and you can try adjusting it to different values to see what works best for you.

Comment: I had already tried that and the problem is that as you mention the shadow box moves down so the bottom looks messy.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the border side which you don't want to show like -

```
  border-left: 0;
```

OR in width also, you can manage the same like -

```
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
```

Comment: But that will remove the border, i only want to remove the box shadow but leaving the border as is.

Comment: Oh ok. Then you need to play with CSS and try to move shadow below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no doubt I'm a genius! This solves my problem:

```
.box {
  background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover  transparent;
  border: 4px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #826200;
  outline: 3px solid white;
}

.box:before {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  content: "";
  margin: -9px 0 7px -7px;
  padding: 0 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
```

Thank you everybody for your ideas!